# Get the probabilities out of a sklearn pipeline using GBM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, mlops

I have a pipeline which takes in TFIDF vectorizer and GBM binary classifier and gives me the label and probability. In production, I dont want the label, I just want the probability of 1 coming out of the pipeline. Can I make changes to the pipeline to get just the probability of 1 instead of label and probability of 0 and 1.

```
gbm_pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True)),
    ('gbm',GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state = 23)),
                    ])
```

When I will use this pipeline to predict, it will give me out something like

```
predict [1]
predict_proba [{0: 0.47260814905166626, 1: 0.5273918509483337}]
```

whereas I just want it to be

```
0.5273918509483337
```

PS: I cannot make use of the Pipeline's output. I wish make the changes in the pipeline itself so that instead of getting label and probability, I just get probability of 1

Answer (score 0):

I would just run a for loop in such situations:

```
probab = []
a = [{0: 0.47260814905166626, 1: 0.5273918509483337}]

for x in a:
    probab.append(x.get(1))
```

probabilty is stored in `probab`:

```
print(probab)
```

> [0.5273918509483337]

Comment: The issue is I cannot play around with the pipeline's output. I need to do something in the pipeline itself so that it gives me only probability.